# liferay single database for two applications

Tags: mysql, hibernate, liferay-6, liferay-service-builder

I have a database which is common for two application one of which is running on Liferay and other on spring boot. I am inserting value in one of the tables ( **having primary key set as auto incremented** ) from both the application.

I have the following in service builder

```
<entity name="EntityName" local-service="true" remote-service="false" cache-enabled="false">
<column name="coloumnName" type="long" primary="true" id-type="increment" />
```

Now the application is giving a Duplicate primary key error when it is attempting to insert the value in the table. Anyone have solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id-type="increment"` is indeed used for auto-increment fields. From the usage instructions in the very well documented [service-builder DTD](https://docs.liferay.com/ce/portal/7.0-latest/definitions/liferay-service-builder_7_0_0.dtd.html#column_id-type): (emphasis mine)

> The id-type and id-param values are used in order to create an auto-generated, auto-incrementing primary key when inserting records into a table. This can be implemented in 4 different ways, depending on the type of database being used. **In all cases, the primary key of the model object should be assigned a value of null**, and Hibernate will know to replace the null value with an auto-generated, auto-incremented value. If no id-type value is used, it is assumed that the primary key will be assigned and not auto-generated.

If you follow any other code sample that manually sets a primary key before inserting a new object into the database, that value will be chosen for the ID. As you'll have to implement some parts of the glue code with Service Builder, there's a good chance you already set a primary key somewhere.

If you pass null as the key, you shall get the auto-increment value back after insertion.

Comment: We are not passing anything as key. Still the error persist

Comment: Hmmm... Is there anything being set in the boilerplate generated code?

Comment: I am using following code, that is passing 0 as primary key
`Entity entity = 
    EntityLocalServiceUtil.createEntity(0);
    cv = 
 EntityLocalServiceUtil.addEntity(entity);`